# Regex for decimal input in Javascript having 1 to 3 digits before decimal and 1 to 3 digits after decimal

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I wanted to create a Javascript regex, which accepts

123,
123.123,
12.34,
1.324

But should not accept

1246,
1234.45,
1.2364

Comment: 123 does not have 1 to 3 digits after decimal ... do you mean 1 to 3 digits before and 0 to 3 digits after?

Comment: it can be a number without decimal, but it should be only upto 3 digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
/^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`/^(0|[1-9]\d?\d?)(\.\d{1,3})?$/`

I assume "00" or "01.234" should not be valid. Use the other answers if they should. :)